# Managing devices from powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-7

What are the commands to enable or disable network adapters in powershell 2.0 in windows 7?  In windows 10 there are enable-netadapter and disable-netadapter commands, are there any analogues of these commands in powershel 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Do it using Wmi.

Enable or disable

```
$netadapter = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "Name LIKE '%Wireless%'"

$netadapter.disable() or $netadapter.enable()
```